# Angular: Observable.subscribe desync weird error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to do a lot of queries in a loop using this:

```js
  buildQuestions()
  {
    for(var i = 0;i<this.sections.length;i++)
    {
      this.serviceQue.getQuestionsBySectionId(this.sections[i].section_id)
        .subscribe(rt => this.sections[i].questions=rt,
        er => console.log(er),
        () => console.log("OK"));
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when subscribe call the line rt => this.sections[i].questions=rt, i doesnt have the same value, then send error because for some i, this.sections[i] is undefined.

For example if i have 1 section and i at the start is 0, then it call this.serviceQue.getQuestionsBySectionId(this.sections[i].section_id) with i = 0, but .subscribe(rt => this.sections[i].questions=rt is excecuted with i = 1, i tried to do something like manual sync using this code:

```js
  buildQuestions()
  {
    var last = -1;
    for(var i = 0;i<this.sections.length;)
    {
      if(last!=i)
      {
        last = i;
        this.serviceQue.getQuestionsBySectionId(this.sections[i].section_id)
        .subscribe(rt => this.sections[i].questions=rt,
        er => console.log(er),
        () => i++);
      }
    }
  }
```

but, for some weird reason, when i do that, this.serviceQue.getQuestionsBySectionId(this.sections[i].section_id)
never send a response and do a infinite loop, if i use the first code it send a response, but if i use the second code it never send a response.

someone can help me?

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly how JS works. When the callback is executed the loop has already finished so i will have the length value. You have to put your code in a closure:

```
buildQuestions() {

    this.sections.forEach(section => {
        this.serviceQue.getQuestionsBySectionId(section.section_id)
            .subscribe(rt => section.questions = rt,
                er => console.log(er),
                () => console.log("OK"));
        }
    });      
}
```

More info about this issue: Here you have the explanation of why is this happening: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-closures-with-confidence-85cd1f841a6b

By the way, this is a classic job interview question